# Why is my header/nav bar sliding in when I adjust screen size?

Tags: css

Ok 2 main issues. The nav bar is transparent, I don't know what could be causing this, and when I adjust the screen width the nav bar also shrinks to the left leaving an empty background. I tried width constraints and text-align/justify-content within a flexbox but then I'm unable to set the position to fixed.
[image: This is what shows up]
I want the menu to be responsive on smaller screen sizes(changing width accordingly) and stay fixed at the top of the page, hiding page content on scroll. Here's what I have so far.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #ADEFD1;
}

body{
    width:100%;
}
section{
height:100px;}
#header{
    display:flex;
    position: fixed 
     top: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: 8888;
    box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    padding: 1%;
}
/*Navigation Bar*/
#nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
#nav-bar li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;

}
#nav-bar li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#nav-bar li a:hover{
    color: #088178;
}

#nav-bar li a.active{
    color: #088178;
  }
  #nav-bar li a.active::after{
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    align-content: center;
  }
  
#nav-bar li:after{
    content:"";
    width:0%;
    height: 3px;
    background: black;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#nav-bar li:hover::after{
    width: 100%
}

.logo{
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<section id="header">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/piram.png" class="logo" alt=""></a>
    <div >
        <ul id="nav-bar">
            <li><a  href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="cart.html"><i class=" fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</section>
<section>
    <h1>hey</h1>
</section>
<section>
    <h1>hey</h1>
</section>
<section>
    <h1>hey</h1>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Your `#header` background color appears to have a typo, with only four characters and with no `#` to set a hex color if that's what you're trying to do. Try `#888` or `#888888` instead

Comment: no dice but thanks for the catch. The bottom section and hero landing are also changing with the screen width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #header CSS is missing a semicolon and background color's color syntax is wrong. After you adjust those, your navbar will shrink so then you add `width:100%` to expand full width.

```
display: flex;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
background-color: #888;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
padding: 1%;
width: 100%;
```